# can't create a graph with matplotlib from a csv file / data type issue

Tags: pandas, csv, matplotlib

I'm hoping to get some help here. I'm trying to create some simple bar/line graphs from a csv file, however, it gives me an empty graph until I open this csv file manually in excel and change the data type to numeric. I've tried changing the data type with pd.to_numeric but it still gives an empty graph.

The csv that I'm trying to visualise is web data that I scraped using Beautiful Soup, I used .text method do get rid of all of the HTML tags so maybe it's causing the issue?

Would really appreciate some help. thanks!

Data file: https://dropmefiles.com/AYTUT

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv

my_data = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
my_data_n = my_data.apply(pd.to_numeric)
plt.bar(x=my_data_n['Company'], height=my_data_n['Market_Cap'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide sample data. Otherwise people won't be able to test.

Comment: I added the data file I'm using

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove the link and add a sample of 5–10 lines of your data into your question. You can format it as a pandas dataframe or copy and paste a print out.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file is corrupt. There are commas at the end of each line. Remove them and your code should work. `pd.to_numeric` is not required for this sample dataset.

Test code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_csv('/mnt/ramdisk/my_data.csv')

fig = plt.bar(x=my_data['Company'], height=my_data['Market_Cap'])
plt.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
plt.title("Title")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I added comas when I was saving the web scraped data to separate the cells. Isn't it how the cvs data is stored?

Comment: No. A trailing field separator (comma in your case) will create a new column with null values at the rightmost position. It should not exist.